# Genitiv mit der Beschreibung des Lebens einer Person

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

Soll ich den Genitiv verwenden, wenn ich das Leben einer Person beschreibe? Mein Satz:

> Man kann im Leben Willy Brandt einen passionierten und echten Mann sehen.

Ich habe das Gefühl, dass sich der Genitiv richtig anfühlt, aber ich habe das Gefühl, dass dies fehlgeleitet sein könnte.

Comment: Welchen Genitiv in dem Satz meinst Du?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richtig ist der Genitiv ("im Leben Willy Brandts"). Allerdings ist der Satz auch mit Genitiv misslungen. Was mit

> Man kann im Leben Willy Brandts einen ... Mann sehen

gemeint ist, ist zwar verständlich  -  aber es ist eine schräge Formulierung. Übrigens ist auch der Ausdruck "echter Mann" nicht mehr zeitgemäß, aber das ist ein völlig anderes Thema.

Man kann stattdessen sagen

- Willy Brandt war ein passionierter und echter Mann.
- Willy Brandts Leben zeigt, dass er ein passionierter und echter Mann war.

Comment: +1.Aber trotzdem frage ich mich auch (wohl ähnlich wie du), was ein 'echter' Mann ist. Das ist imho eine Worthülse, die vermutlich ausdrücken soll, dass er Anstand, Aufrichtigkeit und ggf auch die traditionell männlichen Tugenden verkörperte - und vor allem diese lebte. Was heute 'echt' ist, war zu seiner Zeit sicher sehr progressiv und vielleicht auch zu verweichlicht?

Comment: Ich hatte die Idee, dass "echt" in englisch "genuine" ist. Ich sehe jetzt, dass nicht richtig ist. Ist „aufrichtig" in diesem Zusammenhang besser?

Comment: @NolanTremelling planetmaker hat in seiner Antwort einige gute Vorschläge gemacht. Mir persönlich würde im Kontext des Satzes eher "Politiker" oder ggf. "Staatsmann" als "Mann" gefallen. Also: *passionierter und aufrechter Politiker/Staatsmann*.

Comment: Echter Mann: https://www.tagblatt.ch/kultur/buch-buehne-kunst/was-ist-denn-nun-ein-echter-mann-ld.1735832

Answer (score 2):

In Ergänzung zu Paul Frosts völlig richtiger Antwort, und weil zu lang für einen Kommentar: den Satz sollte man des Stils wegen umformulieren.

'echt' ist ein unglückliches Attribut, außer du willst mehr oder minder explizit auch auf seine Männlichkeit anspielen, auch im geschlechtlichen Sinne. Das ist vermutlich so nicht beabsichtigt. Zwei mögliche Alternativen:

> Willy Brandt war ein passionierter Mann. Er verkörperte Aufrichtig— und Zielstrebigkeit und verband diese mit Anstand.

> Willy Brandt war ein passionierter und von klaren Werten geleiteter Mann, der diese nicht nur predigte sondern auch lebte.

So oder ähnlich könnte man das Gleiche ausdrücken wie im von dir gegebenen Satz - je nachdem, was du mit 'echt' beschreiben möchtest. Der Kontext könnte gebieten, andere Eigenschaften stattdessen zu betonen.